# How to Stream and get the required format type Of Object

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a EmpData Object

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EmpData {


    private List<Areas> areasList = new ArrayList<Areas>();


    public List<Areas> getAreasList() {
        return areasList;
    }
    public void setAreasList(List<Areas> areasList) {
        this.areasList = areasList;
    }


}
```

and a Area Object

```
public class Areas {
    private String areaName;

    public String getAreaName() {
        return areaName;
    }

    public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
        this.areaName = areaName;
    }


}
```

I am trying to loop through the whole empDataList whose AreasList contains "VENG" ,
then get that particular  EmpData

This is my Test Client

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<EmpData> empDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Areas> areasList = new ArrayList<Areas>();


        Areas area1 = new Areas();
        area1.setAreaName("VENG");

        areasList.add(area1);

        EmpData empData1 = new EmpData();

        empData1.setAreasList(areasList);

        empDataList.add(empData1);


        List<EmpData> allData =  empDataList.stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getAreasList().stream()
                .filter(a -> a.getAreaName().equals("VENG")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

}

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Areas> to List<EmpData>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `filter`, not `flatMap`. For each `EmpData` element, apply a filter that streams over the areas `List` to locate the required area name:

```
List<EmpData> allData =  
    empDataList.stream()
               .filter(e->e.getAreasList().stream().anyMatch(a->a.getAreaName().equals("VENG")))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want a single `EmptData` instance, change the terminal operation:

```
Optional<EmpData> emp =  
    empDataList.stream()
               .filter(e->e.getAreasList().stream().anyMatch(a->a.getAreaName().equals("VENG")))
               .findFirst();
```

Comment: Cannot use anyMatch , please suggest

Comment: @user974802 why can't you use `anyMatch`?

Comment: dont want to use whether any elements of this stream  match , but only that element

Comment: @user974802 you wrote that you want "to loop through the whole empDataList whose AreasList contains "VENG" , then get that particular EmpData". That's what my answer does. For each `EmpData`, it requires that its AreasList contains "VENG".

Comment: EmpData ss =  
          empDataList.stream()
                     .filter(e->e.getAreasList().stream().filter(a->a.getAreaName().equals("VENG"))).findFirst().get();

Comment: @user974802 Do you want to obtain a single `EmpData` or a `List<EmpData>`? Based on your attempted code, which ends with `toList()`, I assumed you wanted a `List`.

Comment: @user974802 the inner Stream pipeline in your comment must end in a terminal operation which returns boolean if you are going to pass it to `filter()`.

Comment: I want a single EmpData

Comment: Thanks Eran , but anyMatch will not Suit here , i need to use filter only

Comment: @user974802 if you want to use `filter`, you must pass a `Predicate` to it. That's what I'm doing. Did you try my code?

Comment: @user974802 Why are you against using `anyMatch`?  It does exactly what you want.